# Android CheckBox with indeterminated Status?

Tags: android, checkbox, null, status

in an android-project I need to have a checkbox which may have an indeterminate status, depending on the case if it is optional (true/false/null) or necessary (true/false) to set a value with this checkbox.

While this is possible on MS.Net/WinForms I have no idea if there's a comparable possibility on Java/Android, as I found no documentation about this in the android-docs.

Any ideas about this?
Additional info: the layout is XML-based.

Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible with a check box. What you can do, however, is use a RadioButton and a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html). You can still have just 2 options but you will be able to account for the case where nothing has been selected.